# UITableView shows nothing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I run the application to show the UITableView, it turns out nothing. It will not run :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

1. development environment is IOS SDK 6.1. / simulator version is 6.0.
2. I used table view controller in storyboard.
3. I created a class called "RetrieveDataFromDBTableVC" and set the table view controller's custom class to "RetrieveDataFromDBTableVC". 
   [image]
4. I think the delegate and data source already set up for me, so I do not need to set again right? (The connection of delegate and datasource is Table View).

[image]

5. In "RetrieveDataFromDBTableVC" class I defined like the following:

   ```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self retrieveData];
     }

     -(void)retrieveData
     {
         NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
         NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

         citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

         // Assign data
         NSString * cID = @"aa";
         ...

         cities * myCity = [[cities alloc]initWithCityID:cID andCityID:cName andCityState:cState andCityPopulation:cPopulation andCityCountry:cCountry];

         // Add city object to our cities array
         [citiesArray addObject:myCity];

         // Create a myTableView outlet for this table view to reload data 
         // self.tableView is also correct right?
         [self.myTableView reloadData];
      }

      - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
      {
         // It will not run this function !!
         return [citiesArray count];
      }

      // It will not go into this function either !!
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
        // Set the identifier name in UITableViewCell also
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cities";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Retrieve the current city object for use with this indexPath.row
       cities * currentCity = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       cell.textLabel.text = currentCity.cityName;

       return cell;
     }
   ```

I think the connection is the problem, but I do not know how to figure that out. Thanks !!

Comment: have you implemented `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and the return value is zero?

Comment: You shouldn't create an outlet for the table view, a table view controller has one by default -- you should use [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: @liuyaodong I have not touch anything about that function. The default return value is 0. It will go into this function when I start run the application.

Comment: @liuyaodong Thanks!! After I set the return to 1. It shows up the number. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change this line of your file from: (in the .h file)

```
@interface YourClass : something
```

to:

```
@interface YourClass : something <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

If you haven't already.

Comment: This seems to be a common misconception. Adding the delegate declarations just tells the complier that you intend to implement those protocols, it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's painted as an instance of UITableViewController in IB, and a subclass of UITableViewController, the delegate and datasource are **not** automatically connected.  Connect those explicitly in IB or in code on viewDidLoad.